# Using JNativeHook from an applet in browser

Tags: java, javascript, browser, applet, java-native-interface

I am trying to use JNativeHook from a browser applet to grab a certain keyboard event. I am getting some strange behavior and it does not seem to be working. This is the code I have so far:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import netscape.javascript.*;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class Test extends Applet implements NativeKeyListener { 

    JSObject window;

    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        window.eval("console.log('"+NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()) + "');");
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void init() {
        window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        window.eval("console.log('test');");
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            window.eval("console.log('There was a problem registering the native hook.');");
            window.eval("console.log('"+ex.getMessage()+"');");
            System.exit(1);                
        }

//Construct the example object and initialze native hook.
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(this);
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to callback into a javascript function after a certain key is pressed globally. I have read some stuff about permissions and signing but I am not sure if this is causing an issue for localhost testing (I have to click through warnings).

I am also not 100% on the inner workings of JNativeHook. I am tempted to just write a small DLL for each platform using JNI, but I wanted to check to see if I was missing something fundamental first.

Comment: *"I have read some stuff about permissions and signing but I am not sure if this is causing an issue"* - Yes, how would you like it if so e website loaded an applet that could globally collect information about your keyboard strokes?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I am aware of the implications of executing native code from an applet. The question remains that I do not know exactly how to allow the applet to run the code above from an applet context with the correct permissions when utilizing the JNativeHook jar.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run native code (JNativeHook) from JNLP but you need to sign the code with a valid certificate.  You can run from localhost without one if you want to do some testing.